# Computer Locks Up Completely When Resuming From Standby

Tags: windows-7, freeze, desktop-computer, standby

Okay, so I'm having a strange issue lately with my desktop, and off the top of my head I'm not sure what the problem is, so I'm hoping for some ideas on how to track down the cause.

First, my PC:

> AMD Phenom 9600 Quad-Core 2.4 GHz
>   4 GB DDR2
>  160 GB boot HDD
>  1 TB
>   & 120 GB secondary HDD
>  Nvidia
>   GeForce 8600 GTS
>  Windows 7
>   Professional 64-bit

I have my power settings as follows:

> Turn off the display: 10 minutes 
>   
> Turn off hard disk: 20 minutes 
>   
> Sleep after: Never

After a while, I'll come back to use my computer again, wiggle the mouse, and the screen comes back on like normal, but the desktop is unresponsive. I can move the cursor, but nothing responds to clicks or keyboard entry. If I click a few times with the mouse, the computer eventually locks up completely and the mouse cursor stops moving as well. After I restart, everything works just fine.

Is there a log you recommend checking or really any suggestions would be welcome at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: Shut off the Hard Disk power down and see what happens (set it to never).

Comment: Just changed it, so I'll see if that has any effect. That had crossed my mind as well, possibly the hard drive isn't waking up properly?

Comment: That actually seems to have worked. No problems as of yet. Should I be looking into replacing my drive? Or could it just be a problem with the OS?

Answer (score 1):

Though not necessarily regarded as a solution but rather a workaround, disabling hard disk spin down seems to have resolved the issue for the asker as well as me in my situation which was about the same. My machine however was entirely unresponsive and no display/mouse control was brought up.

The underlying issue may have to do with the BIOS configuration or motherboard incompatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed any new software in the last week, try uninstalling it.  If that doesn't work, try using a virus removing tool (unless you've been using antivirus SW all along).

Comment: I've been running MSE for malware, and I've not installed anything new lately.